# Open custom port for IIS windows firewall or group policy

Tags: iis, group-policy, windows-sbs, windows-firewall

I am running Windows SBS 2011. I have added a web site to IIS using port 8888 and it works perfectly when connecting locally, but not from any other PC on the network (domain).

I think I need to open port 8888 on Windows Firewall but the "Change Settings" button is disabled because of Group Policy.

I need to know how to either:

1. Enable that button (i.e. where do I find the setting that disables it?)
2. Open port 8888 in Group Policy

Comment: You're able to allow a connection port by the firewall only. So you need administrative rights. **Why don't you log in as server administrator and solve it simply?** You would need to handle with GPO only for regular users that need these privileges. Do you want it definetely? Then you'll need the administrator power too.

Answer (score -1):

you can manage windows fw policy in GPO's.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490626.aspx

Comment: I have seen this article before, however I have played with each of the settings and so far have been unable to work out which one will accomplish point 2 described in my question, i.e. how to open port 8888 through GPO. Do you know which one it is?